# Linux Multiple websites behind a single External IP

Tags: linux-networking, centos7

I have a fully qualified domain name (for example myfqdn.com) and it is set up with the registrar and name servers to send all requestes to my external / public IP address (for example 79.79.x.x).

I have to Centos machines, both running Centos V7.3.1611, Webmin V1.851, Bind V9.9, Apache 2.4.6

I have one machine named as system1.myfqdn.com with a internal IP of 192.168.1.200 this machine accepts all incoming requests
The second is system2.myfqdn.com with an internal IP of 192.168.1.250

I am trying to preferably redirect all traffic that is recieved for system2 to 192.168.1.250 using the domain *.system2.myfqdn.com, where * can be www, ftp etc. while system1 handels all other requests, both as a default, or specifically names to system1.

I have tried to route just the web traffic using apaches mod_proxy, but all I was able to see from outside the network was the default page served from 192.168.1.200

I have also tried using the SRV record in bind using

```
reroute.myfqdn.com. in  A   192.168.1.250
_http._tcp.testbed.myfqdn.com.  IN  SRV 0 0 80 reroute.myfqdn.com.
```

This is not to load balance, but to act as a redirect.

I have root access to both machines via ssh and physically as well as the controls that webmin gives.

I also have spare hardware if needed, but the one thing I can not get at this moment, is a second static IP.

If you need any clarification, drop a comment.

Thanks in advance.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use another server or VM running Nginx configured as a reverse proxy. All inbound traffic on your single IP would be directed to the reverse proxy, which would then, in turn, forward the request to the appropriate internal server. 
You would configure your hosts (one for each internal server) in Nginx, much like Apache, but Nginx would not serve up the content directly. It would be fetched as needed from your internal Apache servers.

The specifics of how to set one up are a bit long for an answer here, but there's a good article on how to do it here: https://www.techandme.se/set-up-nginx-reverse-proxy/
Or, by doing a bit of searching for "how to set up a reverse proxy using Nginx", you can find many more.

Comment: I assume that this will only work on the http requests rather than on all traffic?

Comment: Nginx does not support proxying FTP, but if all your incoming FTP requests go to a specific internal host, you could forward incoming FTP to that host directly and only use Nginx to direct HTTP/HTTPS requests. If you do need multiple internal servers for FTP, things get a bit more complicated, as FTP doesn't really support virtual hosting. You might try mounting the storage for FTP files on server 2 under a subdirectory of server 1 and accessing all FTP from the server 1 internal host, if such a thing is practical in your case.